# Identify JsonObject vs JsonArray using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following validator which checks if a JSON string is valid using `Gson`.   It works well with a JSON object but it blows up when you pass it a JSON array.

**JsonStringValidator**

```
public class JsonStringValidator implements ConstraintValidator<JsonString, String> {

    private static final TypeAdapter<JsonObject> strictGsonObjectAdapter =
            new Gson().getAdapter(JsonObject.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String jsonString, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        try {
            try (JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(jsonString))) {
                strictGsonObjectAdapter.read(reader);
                reader.hasNext();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Works**

```
{
  "books":[
    {
      "isbn": "12345"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Fails**

```
[
  {
    "isbn": "12345"
  }
]
```

**Exception**

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonArray
```

So it seems like I also need a `strictGsonArrayAdapter`.

But how can I determine if it's an array or object before calling `strictGsonObjectAdapter`?

Comment: `Gson` objects are used for _serialization_ and _deserialization_. You don't need to do either of those, and simply _parse_ the string (by analyzing the input stream token): ```try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(json)) ) { final JsonToken jsonToken = jsonReader.peek(); return jsonToken == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY || jsonToken == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT; } catch ( final IOException ex ) { throw new RuntimeException(ex); }```

Comment: Do you only want to validate that the JSON is valid, or do you want to validate the content as well? Note that even in strict mode Gson slightly deviates from the RFC regarding which escape sequences are supported by allowing more than the RFC does ([related Gson issue](https://github.com/google/gson/pull/1609#pullrequestreview-473006506)).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine whether the JSON string was an array or an object by using `JsonParser` to give me a `JsonElement`.

The `JsonElement` class has boolean methods for `isJsonArray()` and `isJsonObject()`.

```
JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(jsonString);
log.info(jsonElement.isJsonArray());
log.info(jsonElement.isJsonObject());
```

Comment: You don't need to do it like that. `JsonElement` will hold the entire JSON document that may have a significant performance penalty for strings that are already huge, whereas streamed reading I suggested above will only peek the very first JSON non-whitespace token, and will return `JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT` and `JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY` for `{` and `[` respectively having as small performance impact as possible.

Comment: @fluffy thanks for mentioning that.  if you like, add that as an answer and i will mark it as accepted.